# Applying the simple majority rule to nodes in a random network using R

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph

I have created a random (Erdos-Renyi) network using R (and the igraph package), that has 100 nodes. Each node has been randomly assigned with an attribute of either 0 or 1.

I need to apply the simple majority rule on these nodes so that if the majority of a node's neighbors have the attribute of 0, then the node's attribute changes to 0 as well (or 1 if the majority have 1). It needs to go through all of the nodes in the network iteratively, according to their numbers (1-100), and applies the simple majority rule.

Also, I'm not sure how to iterate through every node again and again until the nodes stop updating.

Can anybody suggest a solution please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not a bunch of code-writing fairies that can write code for you based on (vague) specifications. Please demonstrate your attempts to solve the problem before asking for a solution.

Comment: Please read some of the guidelines for SO: [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [**here**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**here**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). ["Questions asking for code must include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this for a graph g:

```
for (i in 1:100) {
    ones <- 0
    zeros <- 0

    #look through the neighbors of the node and count how many ones and zeros it
         #is connected to        

    modified = FALSE

    if (ones > zeros) {
        if (V(g)$value[which(V(g) == i)] == 0) {
            modified = TRUE
            V(g)$value[which(V(g) == i)] = 1
        }
    } else if (ones < zeros) {
        if (V(g)$value[which(V(g) == i)] == 1) {
            modified = TRUE
            V(g)$value[which(V(g) == i)] = 0
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not going to write the code to look through the neighbors of the node and count how many ones and zeros it is connected to. You can do that easily.

But the code I have provided would go through all of the adjacent nodes of the node you're looking at, and change its attribute value (to 0 or 1) depending on the value of its adjacent nodes.

Answer (score 2):

A cursory look at your code indicates to me that your code *should* work (but I am not familiar with the igraph package).

A couple of possibilities I can think of:

1. `set.vertex.attribute` is not working the way you expect
2. All your nodes are *already* the simple majority of their neighbours.

To assess both cases, when you check your condition `one > zero`, you should also check whether the result is actually changing the node.

This will also help you later when you apply this rule to the network until nothing changes: simply create a flag, `modified = FALSE`, then set it to `TRUE` if any nodes are updated. You can then simply wrap your existing code in a `while` loop: `while(!modified)`

Comment: Inside the if statement at the end, you want to check whether `get.vertex.attribute` of the node is the same as the attribute you are now setting it to. I.e. if the simple majority of a node is 1, and its `get.vertex.attribute` is 0, you would set the modified flag to `TRUE`, and vice-versa.

Then, each iteration of the while loop at the beginning, reset the flag to `FALSE`. That way each time you get the simple majority of all ten nodes, you can see afterwards whether any have been updated.

Comment: No, you need to check if it is being modified, not just set the flag.

Comment: I'll describe it for the first condition: `one > zero`. Simply change the numbers for the second condition. 
Before assigning the node's attribute to 1 (`V(graph)$value[which(V(graph)==i)] = 1`), first check if the node *is already* 1. If it isn't, set `modified` to `TRUE`: `if(V(graph)$value[which(V(graph)==i)] == 0) { modified = TRUE } else { V(graph)$value[which(V(graph)==i)] = 1 }`

Comment: You will. You will also need to set `modified` to `FALSE` at the beginning of the `while` loop, otherwise it will continue forever.

Comment: Also, how do I initialize the modified flag? Is it like this: `modified <- FALSE`? I add this just before the while loop right?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to add it before the `while` loop as well.

Comment: Ok, i thought this might happen, but wanted to simplify the answer. It might run forever because it never reaches a point where nothing changes. We're going to change the `while` loop to a `for` loop, and set a maximum number of iterations, so it will finish (see next comment).

Comment: replace `while(!modified)` with `for(i in 1:1000)`. Then at the end of your code block add, `if(!modified) break`: this needs to come right before the last `}`.

Comment: Is there a way to store how many nodes have 0 and how many have 1 after each iteration, maybe as a data frame? Also, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: I've made changes to my code from above. I have that so far, but at the moment, I'm just printing the number of iterations and how many 0s and 1s there are after each iteration. The result is: `[1] 0` `[1] 49` `[1] 51` `[1] 1` `[1] 12` `[1] 88` `[1] 2` `[1] 0` `[1] 100`. It just prints the number of iterations (0, 1 and 2 in this result) that take place, and the number of 0s (49, 12 and 0) and 1s (51, 88 and 100) there are. I'm not sure how to store these numbers in a data frame.

Comment: It's a bit tricky, because you don't know how many iterations there are going to be. The best thing to do is to create a `dataframe` before the for loop, with 3 columns, and 1000 rows (the total number of possible iterations), filled with `NA`s. You might want to look at the `data.frame` and `rep` functions: these can be combined to achieve this.  Once you have this dataframe, you can simply fill out the appropriate row in the dataframe where your print statements are.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help @Manetheran. I finally managed to get everything working :)